# How to dial a mobile from django modelform?

Tags: python, django, mobile

I wish to dial a mobile number saved on my modelform in django. How do I really do it? Can I get some sample code for the same? I don't know the related interfaces to use or javascript. If I get a full sample code for the same, I will be grateful. My sample model is simple:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
   mobile = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

Just by clicking the button, I would like to dial his mobile number on the modelform. I wish to use the application on a smartphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The most broadly supported scheme is tel: as described in RFC3966
>   [RFC3966]. Code such as the following can be used to enable
>   "Click-to-Call":
>
> `<a href="tel:[PHONE-NUMBER]">[PHONE-NUMBER]</a>`
>
> Note that [PHONE-NUMBER] should always be entered using the full
>   international prefix (e.g. +1-201-555-0111) to ensure that it works
>   outside of its home country.
>
> Similarly RFC5724 [RFC5724] can be used to send a GSM SMS (text
>   message) as follows:
>
> `<a href="sms:[PHONE-NUMBER]?body=[MESSAGE]">[PHONE-NUMBER]</a>`

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/mwabp/#RFC3966

Note that this is not Python or Django specific. It's just HTML an can be rendered by any language/framework.